# Some warnings being treated as errors while making a modified ver of ext2 kernel module under ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, gcc-warning

I have succeeded in making a modified version of ext2 (so called myext2.ko) and tested it for mount and umount, and something else; the problem occurs when I add the following code into my fs/myext2/file.c and tried to implement a simple "encryption" func, that is, negating the last bit of the read-in string :

```
ssize_t my_new_sync_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct iovec iov; //changed
    struct kiocb kiocb;
    struct iov_iter iter;
    ssize_t ret;
    //inserted by adward - begin
    size_t i;
    char buff[len];
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        buff[i] = buf[i] ^ 1;
    }
    iov.iov_base = (void __user *)buff;
    iov.iov_len = len;
    printk("Inside my_new_sync_write");
    //inserted by adward - end
    init_sync_kiocb(&ki_nbytesocb, filp);
    kiocb.ki_pos = *ppos;
    kiocb.ki_nbytes = len;
    iov_iter_init(&iter, WRITE, &iov, 1, len);

    ret = filp->f_op->write_iter(&kiocb, &iter);
    if (-EIOCBQUEUED == ret)
        ret = wait_on_sync_kiocb(&kiocb);
    *ppos = kiocb.ki_pos;
    return ret;
}

ssize_t my_new_sync_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *ppos)
{
    struct iovec iov = { .iov_base = buf, .iov_len = len };
    struct kiocb kiocb;
    struct iov_iter iter;
    ssize_t ret;

    //inserted by adward - begin
    size_t i;
    //inserted by adward - end
    init_sync_kiocb(&kiocb, filp);
    kiocb.ki_pos = *ppos;
    kiocb.ki_nbytes = len;
    iov_iter_init(&iter, READ, &iov, 1, len);

    ret = filp->f_op->read_iter(&kiocb, &iter);
    if (-EIOCBQUEUED == ret)
        ret = wait_on_sync_kiocb(&kiocb);
    *ppos = kiocb.ki_pos;

    //inserted by adward - begin
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
        buf[i] ^= 1;
    }
    printk("inside my_new_sync_read");
    //inserted by adward - end

    return ret;
}
```

The prototype of the above two functions are actually in fs/read_write.c , using by almost all file system types in the kernel code ver 3.17.6; I just copied them into fs/myext2/file.c and make some minor change as commented, so that I can do some test without having to change any Makefile.

But the moment I paste them into my file.c, "sudo make" gives the error message as following:
`/home/adward/linux-3.17.6/fs/myext2/file.c:64:15: error: storage size of ‘kiocb’ isn’t known
  struct kiocb kiocb;
               ^
/home/adward/linux-3.17.6/fs/myext2/file.c:65:18: error: storage size of ‘iter’ isn’t known
  struct iov_iter iter;
                  ^`

and `cc1: some warnings being treated as errors`

even if I haven't refered to them by changing the func pointers in `file_operations` in the same source code file, or say, I haven't used them!

P.S.
My file_operation struct now looks like:

```
const struct file_operations myext2_file_operations = {
.llseek     = generic_file_llseek,
.read       = new_sync_read, //want to replace with my_new_sync_read
.write      = new_sync_write, //want to replace with my_new_sync_write
...
}
```

Has anyone who have done something similar and crashed into some problems like this one? Please notify me if I have done something remarkable wrong, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Met the same error before. U should add `<linux/aio.h>` as ext2 uses asynchronous IO for reading/writing files.
Hope that helps :)